# How can I create a comma-separated list in SAPUI5?

Tags: xml, odata, sapui5

I try to make a comma-separated list of authors in a `headerObject`.

I have a binding and expand a list of authors (ManyToMany):

```
<ObjectHeader responsive="true" fullScreenOptimized="true" title="{database>Title}" intro="{i18n>details_by} {database>AuthorDetails}">
```

This code gives me the following result:

[image: Screenshot of UI]

With `{database>AuthorDetails/Name}` it shows me nothing. How can I expand the authors?

Comment: How did you fill your "database" model? Please provide the code snipped. I think the problem could be solved by adding a "/" like this: "database>/AuthorDetails/Name"

Comment: If `{database>AuthorDetails}` has list of values then its not possible as the `intro` property of object header does not support _Aggregation binding_. You can achieve it only when you will get the list of _Author details with count_ in the form of _string_ from the backend which is separated by some string format(like by underscore). While binding you need to pass the string to the _custom formatter_ and build your desire string format by splitting the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think we can simplify have function in the controller

```
commaSeparator: function(oData) {
    if (oData === null) {
        return "";
    }

    var oModel = this.getView().getModel("database");
    return oData.reduce(function(result, authorKey) {
      var obj = oModel.getProperty("/" + authorKey);
      return result === "" ? obj.Name : result + ", " + obj.Name;
    }, "");
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay thanks for your ideas. I have solved this now.

view:

```
 intro="{path: 'database>AuthorDetails', formatter: '.commaSeparator'}
```

controller:

```
        commaSeparator: function(oData) {
        if (oData === null) {
            return "";
        }

        var authorArray = [];

        for (var i in oData) {
            var authorKey = oData[i];
            var authorObject = this.getView().getModel("database").getProperty("/" + authorKey);
            authorArray.push(authorObject.Name);
        }

        var commaSeparatedString = authorArray.join(", ");
        return commaSeparatedString;
    },
```